# Difference between defining sprite's x, y coordinates, and painting object in some location

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, canvas, sprite

I have a task:

I need to place about 100 sprites on one canvas (with prepared grid on it). I need to place them as invisible (circles) stones, on the board, and make visible only on mouseover.

The problem I come across is following, I can't place those objects accurately into the nodes on the grid.

E.g.

if I define stones (it's just a sprite, as I said earlier) this way:

```
var stone:StoneSprite = new StoneSprite();
    stone.x = this.x + 2*cellWidth;
    stone.graphics.beginFill( 0x000000 );
    stone.graphics.drawCircle(stone.x , this.y + cellWidth, cellWidth/3 );
    stone.graphics.endFill();
    rawChildren.addChild(stone);
```

They don't sit on the node...
See image:
http://img.skitch.com/20091014-kuhfyjeg1g5qmrbyxbcerp4aya.png

And if I do it this way:

```
var stone:StoneSprite = new StoneSprite();
    stone.graphics.beginFill( 0x000000 );
    stone.graphics.drawCircle(this.x + 2*cellWidth , this.y + cellWidth, cellWidth/3 );
    stone.graphics.endFill();
    rawChildren.addChild(stone);
```

The stone is displayed correctly in the grid node... See image 2:
http://img.skitch.com/20091014-f595tksjxramt98s7yfye591bh.png

So I wonder what is the difference between these 2 approaches.

Also, I think I need to pass correct coordinates to the stone class... In case I would like to change some properties of the stone object. E.g. visibility, or radius.

1. Could you please suggest, what's wrong in defining coordinates as stone.x, stone.y
2. How to fix the problem with incorrect positioning.

Would really appreciate ideas about the problem, I am trying to solve for so long :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume x & y are 30 and cellWidth is 30.

First Example:

```
stone.x = 30 + 60; //90
drawCircle(90, 60, 10);
```

This means if you were to draw a rectangle around your circle, it would be at [170,50]. (x,y).

Second Example:

```
stone.x = 0;
drawCircle(90, 60, 10)
```

This means the rectangle around your circle is at [80,50];

---

In the first example, you are moving the sprite to position `x==90`. Then drawing a circle whose *center* is at `x==90` *inside* the sprite. So relative to `this`, you're at `x==180`. But because a circle's x,y coords are the center, subtract 10 for the radius to get the boundary x position.

In the second example, the sprite defaults to position `x==0` relative to `this` and you're drawing the circle inside the sprite at position `x==90`. (therefore it begins at `x==80`).

Comment: So...from the first example it appears that drawCircle uses x this way

drawCircle(begining of the sprite (90) + what I posted here  (90) = 180,60,10)

So that's why, I should use 0 instead... And the item will be drown in the center of Sprite. Correct?

Comment: Just checked... Setting it to 0 did the trick! THANKS A LOT! YOU REALLY HELPED!!

Comment: No worries. Just remember. The center of the circle is the (x,y) of the drawCircle function, relative to the sprite. The sprite itself will still be at postion (0,0) relative to its parent unless you set the (x,y) of "stone" as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's causing the issue - might be some padding induced by the container - can't say without testing. But I believe that adding a Sprite (say board) to `canvas.rawChildren` and using it as the parent for the grid and stones would fix the issue.